# How to remove part of an entry (for several entries) in Python-Pandas DataFrame object

Tags: python, pandas

The goal of my project is to retrieve wind data from an open source and plot it. I want to plot Time (X-axis) vs Measure (Y-axis) from the Pandas DataFrame object below. However, I would like to remove from the Time column the last part, ':00' before using plot functions from Matplotlib. So 11:50:00 should be become 11:50 and so on.

What's the best way to do this?

```
     Time      Date          Measure

215  11:50:00  13/02/2018    17.67

216  12:00:00  13/02/2018    18.19

217  12:10:00  13/02/2018    19.52
```

Comment: Is your time column a string type or pandas DateTime type?

Comment: In the debugger I see: dtype: object

Comment: I use read_csv to retrieve the data. In the csv file time is denoted as, 11:50:00, 12:00:00 and so on. I guess, as you suggested, I have to convert time to string or datetime to apply the proposed solutions.

Comment: To check data type of one of those items, I would suggest doing this on the first element: `type(df.loc[215, 'Time'])` and see what type they are individually. After that, you can decide whether to change them to string or datetime.

Comment: In[21]: type(df9.loc[215, 'Time'])
Out[21]: str

Comment: df['Time'].str[:-3] does the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your `Time` column is of type `string`, you can remove the seconds in your time using:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].str[:-2]
```

if it's datetime, the following will set seconds to zero but will still show the seconds:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].map(lambda x: x.replace(second=0))
```

So you can first change it to string and then  crop the seconds from it.